# How to use computed based on props

Tags: vuejs3, vue-composition-api, computed-properties, vue-props

I try to compute a value based on a props value like this:

```js
interface Props {
  task: Task;
}

const totalPrice = computed(() => {
  return task.paymentDetail.products
    .map(p => p.amount)
    .reduce((partialSum, acc) => partialSum + acc, 0);
})
```

And then in my template I show the computed value `totalPrice` like this: `{{ totalPrice }}`.

My computed is never compute, if I add a console.log inside I never enter it.

How to compute a value based on a props?

Comment: `return props.task.....`

Comment: could you provide it as an answer so I can validate it @MichalLevý

Comment: except when you're coming from vue2 where it was easy and everything was accessible using `this`. Now you have to use `props.` for props and add `.value` for basic data, but not in template because why not

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is an [examplary StackBlitz instance](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-aiypxr?file=src%2FMyComponent.vue,src%2FApp.vue,src%2Fmain.js) using the Composition API without `<script setup>`. If you want to use `<script setup>`, try:

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
import { computed } from 'vue';

interface Props {
  task: Task;
}

const props = defineProps<Props>()
const totalPrice = computed(() => {
  return props.task.paymentDetail.products
    .map((p) => p.amount)
    .reduce((partialSum, acc) => partialSum + acc, 0);
});
</script>

<template>
  {{ totalPrice }}
</template>
```

Comment: If need to change totalPrice, how to change?

Comment: @JackChouMine you change one of the dependencies, e.g. `props.task.paymentDetail.products` in this case. You can't "write" to computed properties directly. Other options would be using get/set and have some underlying logic

Comment: I knew it. I just want to find a best way. tow mehod to change. 1. in set emit a event, but we have to lisenter in parent component. 2. define a data  A  in child component, then make a computed B from A and watch props and change A, B will change. Which is better?

Comment: OMG. Vue used to be SIMPLE. Thanks for this answer

Comment: @OyaMist No problem! I think with script setup, it is still very concise to be fair. The biggest part is still the business logic :D

Answer (score 5):

I just want to add something to the accepted answer: **Do NOT use de-structured props inside computed functions.** They won't detect the changes made to the values.

## This works

```js
const props = defineProps(['something'])
const computedValue = computed(() => {
  // This computed value will be re-calculated every time props.something changes
  return props.something + props.something
}
```

## This doesn't

```js
const { something } = defineProps(['something'])
const computedValue = computed(() => {
  // This computed value will only be calculated once and never again after
  return something + something
}
```